# WPF member not recognized

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**UserControl**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="RecipeApp.Components.FilterCheckbox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             x:Name="root"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="BorderedCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <!-- Border -->
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Background="White">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="False">
            <CheckBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" Background="White" x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="15,15,15,15"  >
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding CBText,ElementName=root}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                            <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </CheckBox.Template>
        </CheckBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**FilterCheckbox.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace RecipeApp.Components
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for FilterCheckbox.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public class FilterCheckbox : UserControl
  {


    public string CBText
    {
      get { return (string)GetValue(CBTextProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CBTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CBText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CBTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(name: "CBText", propertytype: typeof(string), ownerType: typeof(FilterCheckbox), typeMetadata: new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


    public FilterCheckbox()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
 
    }

}
```

**Main.xml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="RecipeApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RecipeApp.Components"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="13*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="67*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Background="White" Width="Auto" >
            <StackPanel.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Opacity="0.505" ShadowDepth="3" />
            </StackPanel.Effect>
            <Label Content="Search" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Width="116.6" Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <StackPanel Width="100"/>
            <StackPanel Height="100" Margin="5,20,5,0">
                <local:FilterCheckbox CBText="32wd" />
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="-4.2,0,0,0" Background="#FFE1EFC9"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Error**
The member "CBText" is not recognized or is not accessible
Error originates from the main xaml file when calling the FilterCheckbox component

I am trying to create my own custom components for my Application I was following some tutorials but i keep on getting this issue.

I have tried changing the property name from "Text" to "CBText" to try resolve the issue but no such luck.

Help will be greatly apricated

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error?

Comment: in the main xaml file when i call the component

Comment: Better [edit] your question to make this clear. Such information is easily overlooked if placed in the comments.

Comment: Tried the follwing?: remove control from main, build solution/project, reinclude control, build again

Comment: That is probably just an error message in the XAML designer. Rebuild your project to make it disappear.

Comment: I removed the Component from main and now it gives me this the Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'FilterCheckbox'; another partial declaration of this type exists

I dont see any other components or objects with the name FilterCheckbox

Comment: I have tried rebuild but it wont due to the error

Comment: @SanchoPanza removing the component and then rebuilding fixed it it also showed more errors that weren't showing thanks